# How to link a text field with a radio button

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

Before Clicking anything text field should be disable . when after the radio button selected my text field must be enable.

Comment: You are looking to do conditional rendering of React components.  What have you tried already?  Please provide code samples.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the working solution of your question.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isRadioSelected: true
  };
  changeHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ isRadioSelected: false });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h3>Input text is {this.state.isRadioSelected ? 'Disabled': 'Enabled'}</h3>
        <input type="text" disabled={this.state.isRadioSelected} />
        <br />
        <label>Select Radio Button</label>
        <input type="radio" onChange={this.changeHandler} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description is pretty vague and you don't have any code samples, but here's likely what you want to do:

1. Make the radio button a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), so that you can access it's value within React's state.
2. Tie the input's `disabled` attribute to the value of that state field.

It also seems like you want a checkbox, and not a radio button, since a radio button cannot be untoggled if there is only a single radio button.

This code will likely not work as-is (I haven't run it), but should provide a starting idea:

```
function Tester() {
  const [radioValue, setRadioValue] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="radio" onClick={(e) => setRadioValue(e.target.value)} value={radioValue} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="your input box" disabled={!radioValue} />
    </div>
  )
}
```